# Why is the Java Priority Queue not empty after execution in the following code?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am trying to implement Dijkstra Algorithm and have used the following code. I have used the debugger in Eclipse to step through the program and have found that it produces correct values mid way through the execution. However after that, the priority queue that I have used from the java.util package, does not show up to be empty. While theoretically it should be empty from the following code.

From the debugger, it can be seen that the priority queue contains references with values set to Infinity. What is the bug in the code?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;


public class Dijkstra {
    static class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>{
        private int vertexid;
        private Double distance;

        public Vertex(int vertexid, Double distance) {
            this.vertexid = vertexid;
            this.distance = distance;
        }

        public int getVertexid() {
            return vertexid;
        }

        public Double getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
            return this.getDistance().compareTo(other.getDistance());
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Vertex) {
                Vertex v = (Vertex) o;
                return vertexid == v.vertexid && distance == v.distance;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void dijkstra(double g[][], int n, int m, int source) {
        // g is the adjacency matrix
        // n is the number of nodes
        // m is the number of edges

        // initialize shortest path

        double d[] = new double[n];


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            d[i] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        d[source] = 0;

        HashMap<Integer, Double> s = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> q = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();

        // initialize q
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            q.add(new Vertex(i, d[i]));
        }

        Vertex u;

        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            u = q.remove();
            //System.out.println(u.getVertexid() + "\t" + u.getDistance());
            s.put(u.getVertexid(), u.getDistance());

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (i != u.getVertexid() || g[u.getVertexid()][i] != Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
                    if (u.getDistance().doubleValue() + g[u.getVertexid()][i] < d[i] && s.containsKey(i) == false) {
                        q.remove(new Vertex(i, d[i]));
                        d[i] = u.getDistance().doubleValue() + g[u.getVertexid()][i];
                        q.add(new Vertex(i, d[i]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*for(double i: d){
            System.out.println(i);
        }*/

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double graph[][] = {{Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 4, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 8, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY},
                {4, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 8, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 11, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY},
                {Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 8, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 7, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 4, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 2},
                {Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 7, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 9, 14, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY},
                {Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 9, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 10, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY},
                {Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 4, 14, 10, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 2, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY},
                {Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 2, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 1, 6},
                {8, 11, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 1, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 7},
                {Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 2, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 6, 7, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY}
               };

        Dijkstra.dijkstra(graph, 9, 14, 0);

    }
}
```

The following are the references from the debugger:

[image]

And for the Priority Queue Contents:

[image]

After the execution the s values all get set to infinity.

Comment: The `PriorityQueue.isEmpty()` method must have returned true, which means the PQ *is* empty, by definition. The underlying array mightn't be empty, but peeking into internals isn't valid.

Comment: This question should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @krokodilko Why? He hasn't asked for a review of his code. He has asked why it isn't working as expected. That is what SO is for.

Answer (score 1):

```
// initialize q
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    q.add(new Vertex(i, d[i]));
}
```

There should only be the source element in the queue in first place. You should not insert all the infinity distances to the queue. Only the source should be in the queue. And then while processing the source you insert the nodes reachable from source, and then process the nearest node among the nodes. That's how this algorithm work. So remove the for loop where you are inserting all the nodes into the queue. Insert only the source in queue before starting while loop. 
Example:

```
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        d[i] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    d[source] = 0;

    HashMap<Integer, Double> s = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> q = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();

    // initialize q
    // only the source in the queue with 0 distance.

    q.add(new Vertex(source, d[source]));

    Vertex u;
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: That's not how the algorithm initializes. Check CLRS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are actually inserting infinity values to the `s`. Your priority value does empty eventually but before that, you are pushing some infinity to the queue and eventually it get inserted into map. For a quick fix, you should check if the value is infinity or not before pushing it into the map. This solved the problem.

```
    System.out.println(u.getVertexid() + "\t" + u.getDistance());
    if(u.getDistance() != Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY){
        s.put(u.getVertexid(), u.getDistance());
    }
```

Although the root cause of infinity lies here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        d[i] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    d[source] = 0;    

...
...
// initialize q
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    q.add(new Vertex(i, d[i]));
}
```

---

except the `d[source]` all other elements in the queue are infinite. And you are inserting this infinite value without checking.

```
u = q.remove();
s.put(u.getVertexid(), u.getDistance());
```

Comment: Doesn't the check < d[i] ensure that the if block doesn't get infinity?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Updated the answer. Check it out now.

Comment: Also you could just break the while loop when `u.getDistance() == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. Because after this all the element in queue are infinite.

Comment: How can the infinity problem lie there. That is how the Algorithm works and the algorithm proceeds by calculating correct values. The problem is that in the end after calculating correct values it ends up setting the valued to infinity. Why does that occur is the main question.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem lies in

```
private Double distance;
```

In the equals function, a `Double` is being compared to a `double`. Hence while the elements are being removed from the priority queue, they are not actually being removed. This can be fixed by changing the above line to :

```
 private double distance;
```

The check produces incorrect values in the following piece of code :

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Vertex) {
                Vertex v = (Vertex) o;
                return vertexid == v.vertexid && distance == v.distance;
            }
            return false;
        }
```